# Going to perform crticial data correction, but want to back up properly

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am not an Oracle or database expert. I will need to perform some data correction in the database and due to our horrible database design there are no proper constraint checks and so on. I will perform the data correction, but if the data causes then the application to become corrupt I would like to revert the changes. Which specific technique/concept is best to use for this purpose in Oracle database?  Essentially if anything goes wrong I want the database to look exactly the same as it did before I did the data correction.

Comment: Basically you're looking for a backup solution. Check those 2 links; (1) https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmintro.htm#BRADV8001 (2) https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/toc.htm

Comment: A few points which need consideration. 1) How soon will you know whether the data fix is running fine or it has corrupted the data. 2) How many tables are impacted by your data fix. Is it widespread of limited to just one or two tables. 3) Can you perform the data fix on a pre-prod environment and ascertain whether is working fine before applying it on the production environment. Here is one option you can consider. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/flashdb.htm#BRADV71000